# KeyPressed/KeyReleased not working?

Tags: java, keypress, keyrelease

I'm trying to make a game in java, just a simple platformer, but I'm having difficulty when running the code. I can't seem to get any response from key presses. The only thing I can think hasn't been working properly is the keyPressed and keyReleased functions. Below is the relevant code.

```
public ReflexPanel() {

    initBoard();

    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000/120, this);
    timer.start();
}

private void initBoard() {

    loadMenu();

    int w = menu.getWidth(this);
    int h = menu.getHeight(this);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
}



private void step() {
    if(mainMenu){
        if(ePressed) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if(hPressed) {
            loadScores();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 'e') {
        ePressed = true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 'h') {
        hPressed = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 'e') {
        ePressed = false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 'h') {
        hPressed = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    step();
}
```

The ePressed and hPressed variables are just booleans set to false by default, and loadScores calls a png file.

Comment: is the focus of the application on the component to which you added your listener(s)?

Comment: Did you implement the event listener meant for it? Like KeyListener ?

Comment: Because if its a panel to listen to, it will be panel.addKeyListener(this) hope this code will be more helpful : and the function KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){ int id = e.getID();
        String keyString;
        if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            keyString = "key character = '" + c + "'";
        } else {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            keyString = "key code = " + keyCode
                    + " ("
                    + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode)
                    + ")";
        }   }

Comment: Stultuske, I'm not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == 'e'){
    // code logic
}
```

[`KeyEvent::getKeyCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode--) doesn't return the char you press on the keyboard. It *"returns the integer keyCode associated with the key in this event"*. When using `KeyEvent::getKeyCode` you have to use the [KeyEvent key constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_E) values predefined in the class. So for example:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_E){
    // code logic
}
```

Or you can use [`KeyEvent::getKeyChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar--) which *"returns the character associated with the key in this event"*.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `getKeyCode()` which returns an `int` value with constants given in `KeyEvent` class, such as `KeyEvent.VK_E`.

You're looking to use `getKeyChar()` which returns `'e'` directly.

```
if (e.getKeyChar() == 'e') {  // Now it has an actual chance of working
```

Comment: Hmm, I've made this edit, but nothing's changed. I wonder if it may be an issue with step() not running properly, although I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't guarantee it'll fix your code, I only guarantee that it definitely won't work without this change. Instead of wondering whether `step()` runs, you should check it. Surely you know how to print out something inside a method? Or better yet, use a debugger.